# PDE reaction diffusion equilibrium solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

I have an idea on how to combine the equations both ways, and can complete the first step of finding $a\cdot t$ and $b \cdot t$, but I'm unsure on how the diagram is meant to look. Can anyone give me a pointer? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you combine both equations, you find

$$
a_t + b_t = 0.
$$

Thus, the function $c(t) = a(t) + b(t)$ satisfies the initial value problem
$$
c' = 0; \quad c(0) = a_0 + b_0.
$$

What is the unique solution of the above IVP?

Then, writing $u = b$, you have

$$
u = \nu_0 - a
$$

so

$$
u_t = -a_t = R_+ - R_- \\
= k_+ab^2 - k_-ab \\
= ba(k_+b - k_-) \\
= b(\nu_0 - b)(k_+b - k_-)\\
= u(\nu_0 - u)(k_+u - k_-)
$$
since $b = u$ and $a = \nu_0 - b = \nu_0 - u$.

To sketch solutions, either plug this into some software (you can find many free ways to do this online), or sketch by hand using what you (should) know about autonomous equations, their equilibrium points, etc..